# Compare and remove duplicates from XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I've following XML document:

```
<root>
<Organization>
    <Organization_ID >111111</Organization_ID>
    <Organization_Code>ABC</Organization_Code>
</Organization>
<Organization>
    <Organization_ID >111111</Organization_ID>
    <Organization_Code>ABC</Organization_Code>
</Organization>
<Organization>
    <Organization_ID >111111</Organization_ID>
    <Organization_Code>ABCD</Organization_Code>
    <Organization_Type>Test</Organization_Type>
</Organization>

</root>
```

I need the output as(removing duplicate records):

```
<root>

<Organization>
    <Organization_ID>111111</Organization_ID>
    <Organization_Code>ABC</Organization_Code>
</Organization>
<Organization>
    <Organization_ID>111111</Organization_ID>
    <Organization_Code>ABCD</Organization_Code>
    <Organization_Type>Test</Organization_Type>
</Organization>

</root>
```

I already wrote a code below which can do this. My issues is that we need to compare all the child elements as see if they are exact duplicates. As soon as I put condition for Organization_Type, output picks all three records

My Code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Organization">
    <xsl:if
        test="
            (not(following::Organization[Organization_ID = current()/Organization_ID])
            or not(following::Organization[Organization_Code = current()/Organization_Code])


            )">
        <xsl:copy>

            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Code which I want to use but isn't working:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Organization">
    <xsl:if
        test="
            (not(following::Organization[Organization_ID = current()/Organization_ID])
            or not(following::Organization[Organization_Code = current()/Organization_Code])
            or not(following::Organization[Organization_Type = current()/Organization_Type])

            )">
        <xsl:copy>

            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any help will be appreciated. Sorry this is my first post so might not be posting at correct place or in correct format.

Comment: I have a question: Do you wish to filter out exact duplicates (all child nodes must be identical for the organisation to be filtered out) or partial duplicates (one child node must be identical for the organisation to be filtered out)?

Comment: Yes, I wan'to filter out exact duplicates. The solution provided below worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stylesheet shows version 2.0, so assuming you are indeed using an XSLT 2.0 process, you can use `xsl:for-each-group` here. Effectively you group by a concatenation of Organization_ID, Organization_Code and Organization_Type but output only the first element in each group, thus removing duplicates.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="root">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="Organization" group-by="concat(Organization_ID, '|', Organization_Code, '|', Organization_Type)">
              <xsl:apply-templates select="." />
          </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```